# Include encoded URL characters in OrchardCMS autoroute displayalias

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I need to assign pre-determined URLs to pages added to Orchard CMS. The URLs contain % encoded values for spaces and dashes and & for example. The URL is assigned properly via autoroutepart, but orchard doesn't seem to be able to find the pages using these urls after the pages are published. Any help will be much appreciated. Let me know if you need more info on the issue.

**Edit**
I am generating the page with a fixed URL using the following code -

```
var route = page.As<AutoroutePart>();
route.DisplayAlias = pageUrl.StartsWith("/") ? pageUrl.Substring(1) : pageUrl;
if (route.ContentItem.Id == 0) 
Services.ContentManager.Create(route);
Services.ContentManager.Publish(route.ContentItem);
```

Example of url I am trying to assign -
http://example.com/OrchardLocal/car-hire/United%20States/Bluefield/Mercer%20County%20Airport%20HLE

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I have edited the original post with more info.

Comment: Can you enable AliasUI and check if your alias is there and what route is associated with it?

Comment: When I enable AliasUI, they show up there and route associated with it is in the form "\Contents\Item\Display\#id" ... and the routes are valid as I can navigate to the pages using that. But not using the encoded url.